# how to query the highest digit in a search?

Tags: vim, vim-registers

Searching for the pattern `/{{c\d`, I'd like to get the highest digit found and use it in a macro.

For context, I'm using Anki (flashcard tool) and its cloze card type, and recently started creating my cards within vim.

Example card:

```
## Front
reading: 
{{c1::A::reading A}}
B
{{c2::C::reading C}}
{{c1::D::reading D}}
E


## Back
...
```

In that example, given I'm positioned above E, I'd like to execute a macro that'll figure out that the highest cloze digit is 2 (in `{{c2::C::reading C}}`) and create a new cloze with highest digit incremented by one as `{{c3::E::reading E}}`

My macro currently looks like this:

```
:registers
"c   ysiw}wysiw}wyiwic3::^OP::reading
```

- `ysiw}` uses vim-surround to wrap the word in braces.
- `wysiw}` repeats that operation
- `wyiw` yanks the word
- `ic3::` adds `c3::` in insert mode <= **How do I calculate 3 from the highest cloze number in the file?**
- `^OP` paste the yanked word in insert mode
- `::reading` adds the remaining text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `:%s` command with the [`/n`] flag, which doesn't execute the substitution but only counts the matches.

Use that together with a [`\=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) expression on the replacement side, just for the side effects of the expression.

You can use that to append the *cloze* numbers to a list and then find the maximum after you've collected them all.

```
function! NextCloze()
    let nums = [0]
    let view = winsaveview()
    silent %s/\m{{c\zs\d\+\ze::/\=add(nums, submatch(0))/egn
    call winrestview(view)
    return 1 + max(nums)
endfunction
```

The function is also saving and restoring the view around the `%s` operation, since that operation will move the cursor and we want to keep it in place.

To insert it in the middle of a mapping you can use something like:

```
i{{c<C-R>=NextCloze()<CR>::
```

Though there are probably other ways you can put that result in your buffer. For instance, if you'd like a mapping that takes the current word under the cursor and replaces it with the `{{cN::...::reading ...}}` block, consider these:

```
nnoremap <Leader>c ciW{{c<C-R>=NextCloze()<CR>::<C-R>"::reading <C-R>"}}<Esc>
xnoremap <Leader>c c{{c<C-R>=NextCloze()<CR>::<C-R>"::reading <C-R>"}}<Esc>
```

In Normal mode, it will act on the Word (sequence of non-white space symbols) under the cursor. In Visual mode, it will act on the visual selection. These are closer to your original `@c` macro.

Comment: @fibranden thanks for the reply, this looks like a brilliant solution, but I'm noticing a weird behavior. The result returned is printed at the first position of the line, not at the position of my cursor. Also, the number returned is not the highest match + 1. I can't even figure out why it returns the number it returns.

Sharing a video where I'm expected 5 to be adding to my cursor, but instead getting a 3 at the beginning of the line: https://youtu.be/gSHx-FoIjEw

Comment: @AdrienLemaire Thanks for the video, easy to troubleshoot it that way! First problem was that I was anchoring the regex with `^` so only looking for it at the beginning of the line. Also missing `/g` to match multiple entries on the same line. Second problem was a little tricky, but it turns out it's because `%s` will move the cursor while going through the buffer, so restoring the view after the operation was enough to get it back in place in a way that `<C-R>=` now works with it.

Comment: This is perfect. I was also wondering how to handle visual selection and you gave me the solution. Thank you very much! 
Really looks like I need to learn a bit of vimscript ^^'

Comment: @AdrienLemaire You're welcome, it's a pleasure!  If you decide to get serious (or more serious) about Vimscript, my suggestion is [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) by Steve Losh as a great place to start. Also check out [vi.se], many Vimscript wizards hanging out over there! Have a great weekend!

Comment: Oh and thanks for the great question! This was one that took a bit of work to figure out. I'm happy to say I learned quite a bit from it too. Especially the bits that didn't work out right away, such as the cursor position when inserting the result of the function... Cheers!